# site open in 3 browsers, typing into textbox in one of them appears in ALL of them

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i am developing a ASP MVC app, and when testing I have 3 browsers open and I am logged in in each of them as a different user.

There I also have a search box, but when I search in any of the browsers, whatever I type in it appears in the other 2 as well, any idea why?

I am using signalr in the project but I am NOT doing it with signalr, I even removed all the JS I had on the page so that live search did not work anymore, but still the text typed in one browser appeared in the others.

any idea why? Could this be IIS glitch?

Here's the text input html and search code though I don't think it will make a difference.

```
<input type="text" class="searchtext" id="searchtext" placeholder="Search friends..." />
                        <ul id="livesearchul"></ul>

$("input#searchtext").keyup(function () {

                var searchVal = $("input#searchtext").val();

                $("ul#livesearchul").empty();

                if (searchVal == "" || searchVal == " ") return false;

                var url = "profile/LiveSearch";

                $.post(url, { searchVal: searchVal }, function (data) {

                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $("ul#livesearchul").append("<li class=close>x</li>");
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var obj = data[i];

                        $("ul#livesearchul").append('<li class=livesearchli><a href="/' + obj.Username + '"><img src="uploads/' + obj.UserId + '.jpg" />' + ' ' + obj.FirstName + ' ' + obj.LastName + '</a></li>');
                    }

                });

            });
```

**EDIT:**

I just re-tested this and actually it has nothing to do with being logged in or searching, the same thing happens if I just have the login form open in all 3 browsers, so if I type in one box in one of them the same text appears in those boxes in the other browsers as well.

Comment: In other two browsers appears same text in inputbox? or appears same result after you click on search button?

Comment: Same text. actually I just retested it and even when not logged in, so for example if i type something in the login form in one browser it appears in the same input box in the other browsers as well.

Comment: This could be caused by the [Browser Link](https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/project-system/browser-link/) feature in Visual Studio. You can disable that feature, follow the steps in the link.

Comment: @JasonEvans Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As my comment answered your question, I'll move it here, so that this question can be closed neatly with an answer.*

This could be caused by the [`Browser Link`](https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/project-system/browser-link/) feature in Visual Studio. You can disable that feature, follow the steps in the link.